# Oracle Apex link to BLOB from different table

Tags: oracle-apex

I've got a form in which I want to display either a download link for a BLOB or use a file browser field to do the same.

I can manage the file browser method normally, however because the BLOB I want to refer to isn't part of the table the form is based on, I can't seem to get it to show properly.
The best I've got so far is a 'display only' field with an SQL query returning the size of the file.

Comment: Have you tried the example Dimitri Gielis explains here: http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2008/07/show-blob-of-other-table-in-apex-form.html

Comment: Still can't seem to get this to work..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle Application Express, you may youse the "P" procedure.

Just like the "F" procedure that you it to show pages, the P procedure allows you to download files from apex.

for example : 
**http://apex.shellprompt.net/pls/apex/p?n**=*217605020644166778* 
where that number at the end is the primary key number form the

```
select id 
  from apex_application_files
```

To add a file to this table, simple add a browse-file item on a page. Run the page, browse for a file, and submit the page. It will automatically insert it in this table. 
 you can query it after :

```
select id 
  from apex_application_files
where filename = YOUR_FILE
```

good post for this is : http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2007/08/oracle-apex-fp-pn-zp.html

test it out, tell me if you get stuck